# How to create a customized dataframe with certain values as columns in pandas (Python3)?

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, statistics, pivot-table

hopefully I can write this in a concise enough way that gets my question at hand across.

Say I connected to a csv in Python via read_csv(). The dataframe looks something like this:

```
ID | Has kids? | Purchases

1  |     Y     |   23
2  |     N     |   17
3  |     Y     |   28
4  |     N     |   11
```

So I want to be able to do a simple independent t-test between the purchases of people that have kids (Y) and people that don't have kids (N) and see if there is a difference between the purchases.

How do I customize a new dataframe from this to have 3 columns: ID, 'Y' and 'N' that have the row values to be the purchases for each given ID?

Eventually I wanted to utilize stats library from scipy and use the stats.ttest_ind() method and just pass the Y and N columns through there to get the results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the dataframe method `pivot()`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "Has kids?": ['Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N'],
    "Purchases": [23, 17, 28, 11],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.set_index('ID')

df.pivot(index=None, columns="Has kids?", values="Purchases")

>>> Has kids?     N     Y
    ID                   
    1           NaN  23.0
    2          17.0   NaN
    3           NaN  28.0
    4          11.0   NaN
```